# How to binarize the columns of a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, encoding, data-processing

I want to binary encode the columns of a numpy array (not one-hot-encoding):

```
a = np.array([[2, 3, 5], [4, 6, 8], [3, 7, 9]], dtype=np.uint8)
```

The output of:

```
>>>print("np.unpackbits(a,axis=1):\n{}".format(np.unpackbits(a, axis=1)))
>>>np.unpackbits(a,axis=1):
[[0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1]]
```

is very closed to my requirements, but there are some redundant zeros in the output array, which is not what I want.

For example, for the first column :`[2,4,3]`, it is encoded as `[0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0, 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0, 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1]` in the output. however, it's sufficient to encode it as `[0 1 0,1 0 0,0 1 1]`.

I wonder whether there exists some off the shelf codes or sklearn/numpy modules that is able to convert the above array into such binary representation without redundant zeros.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ndrrays need to have a "rectangular" shape (in all dimensions) to be performant. You can store tuples like that, but that defeats the purpose of ndarrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to preserve the numpy array structure, you must truncate all the unpacked numbers to the same number of bits. You can determine the number of required bits using this formula:

```
>>> a = np.array([[2, 3, 5], [4, 6, 8], [3, 7, 9]], dtype=np.uint8)
>>> nbits = int(np.floor(np.log2(np.max(a)))+1)
>>> nbits
4
```

You can create a truncated version of np.unpackedbits from `8` to `nbits` by first unpacking over a new axis, truncating, and then reshaping on your desired shape:

```
>>> np.unpackbits(a[...,np.newaxis], axis=2)[:,:,8-nbits:].reshape(a.shape[0],-1)
array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]], dtype=uint8)
```

An other way to get this result is filtering the result of np.unpackedbits over columns:

```
>>> u = np.unpackbits(a, axis=1)
>>> u[:,[i for i in range(u.shape[1]) if i%8>=8-nbits]]
array([[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]], dtype=uint8)
```

Last but not least, if you want to remove all columns containing only zeros, you can use:

```
>>> u[:,u.any(axis=0)]
array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1]], dtype=uint8)
```

---

---

## Edit

If you want the max number of bits to be determined over each column:

```
>>> nbits = (np.floor(np.log2(np.max(a,axis=0)))+1).astype('int')
>>> nbits
array([3, 3, 4])
```

You can then filter columns relatively to this vector:

```
>>> u = np.unpackbits(a, axis=1)
>>> u[:,[i for i in range(u.shape[1]) if i%8>=8-nbits[i//8]]]
array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]], dtype=uint8)
```

This should do the job!

Comment: Hi @ashiakerwang, no problem. Have you managed to solve the problem? If you have any question do not hesitate.

Comment: This is very close to what I want, but it seems the output of `u[:,[i for i in range(u.shape[1]) if i%8>=8-nbits]]` still have some redundant zeros (for example, the first column of the output array   ). Sorry, it's probably because I didn't make it clear in the question.  I think `nbits` should be determined according to the maximum value of each column rather than the maximum item of  `a`.  In other words, `nbits` for the three columns is 3, 3, 4 respectively.

Comment: Ah ok I see. `u[:,u.any(axis=0)]` doesn't do the job because  it also removes the bits located after isn't it?

Comment: I edited the answer, now it should do exactly what you want I think. Your question was very clear I just missed the point that there is "useful" and "unuseful" columns of zeros.

Comment: Great! Maybe you should also consider casting your matrix into booean using [numpy.ndarray.astype](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html) `u=u.astype('bool')`. This may reduce memory consumption and computation time. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Off the shelf you don't have anything so nice. If you're willing to accept some small number of extra bits (we want factors of 8) you can get the result you want with minimal additional effort.

```
# Extract the even-numbered columns.
# Take each uint8 of the form 0000abcd and transform it into abcd0000.
x = a[:,::2]<<4

# The if-statement handles a shape mismatch for odd column counts.
# Take each of the abcd0000 uint8s we just created and add an adjacent
# 0000efgh value to it to get abcdefgh.
if a.shape[1]&1:
    x[:,:-1] += a[:,1::2]
else:
    x += a[:,1::2]

# As long as every element was small enough that there wasn't overflow,
# we just shrank the array by half. Pack it as before.
np.unpackbits(x, axis=1)
```

Using the minimal number of bits is slightly harder for a couple reasons:

1. You need to compute the minimal bit-width. This is just `int(a.max()).bit_length()` though, so don't worry too much about this step.
2. You need to pack each 8-bit integer into your new B-bit lanes. If B isn't a factor of 8 that's fairly painful since a single input integer will span multiple output integers.

In terms of other solutions, you could always incur some substantial runtime overhead and create the unpacked array yourself. The following code is definitely not optimal (and might not run -- somebody ought to test it), but it should be simple enough to illustrate the idea.

```
def bits(x, n):
    def _foo(x):
        for _ in range(n):
            yield x&1
            x >>= 1
    return reversed(_foo(x))

def unpack(L, n):
    for x in L:
        yield from bits(x, n)

width = int(a.max()).bit_length()
result = np.array([list(unpack(L, width)) for L in a], dtype=bool)
```